# Can I code for Windows Phone 8 on VS 2015 with Windows 7?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-7, visual-studio-2015

From [this article](https://www.visualstudio.com/visual-studio-2015-system-requirements-vs) , they said

> If your computer meets the operating system requirements but does not meet the hardware requirements for the Windows Phone Emulators, the Windows Phone development tools will install and run. However, the Windows Phone 8.0 and 8.1 Emulators will not function and you must use a device to deploy or test Windows Phone apps.

So now I'm using win 7 64 bit , can I just use VS 2015 to code and then deploy to a real WP device for debug without using emulator Hyper-V ? Both WP8 app and "Windows 10 mobile" ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Phone 8 SDK is not supported by Windows 7.
Therefore, you will not be able to develop windows phone 8 applications.

Comment: You can, however, develop a Universal Windows Application using Visual Studio 2015 and deploy to a Windows 10 Mobile physical device.